# UiAutomator test with immersive mode, can't click things under navigation bar

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uidevice, android-immersive

I am trying to run tests on my app that runs in immersive mode.

However, when I try and click on things that would normally be where the navigation bar is, nothing happens, because `UiDevice` thinks the screen is smaller than it actually is.

i.e. it think the screen is 2076 pixels tall when it's actually now 2152. Is there anyway to access that extra 76 pixels of screen?

A rough example of my app code is as follows...

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class ScreenShotTest {

private static final String BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE = "my.package.name";

private UiDevice mDevice;

@Before
public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
    context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Initialize UiDevice instance
    mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());

    // Wait for launcher
    final String launcherPackage = getLauncherPackageName();
    assertThat(launcherPackage, notNullValue());
    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);

    // Launch the blueprint app
    final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);    // Clear out any previous instances
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Test
public void allTests() throws InterruptedException, UiObjectNotFoundException {
    int i = 0;
    boolean mainMenuFinished = false;
    while(!mainMenuFinished && i < 600) {
        i++;
        sleep(1000);
        mainMenuFinished = pref.getBoolean(MAIN_MENU_FINISHED, false);
    }

    int j = 0;
    int[] buttonBounds = new int[2];
    for (String s : pref.getString(name, "").split(",")) {
        buttonBounds[j] = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(s));
        j++;
    }

    mDevice.click(buttonBounds[0], buttonBounds[1]);
}
```

I am setting the location in pixels of my button in a shared pref in my actual apk, then my test apk is reading the value and hitting click in that place.

My real app has a screen width of 2152 (Landscape) my test apk only thinks the screen is 2076.

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Which app are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by app? I'm testing my own app.

Comment: I mean if there's a simple way of reproducing it

Comment: Ah. Not really, not simply. I'll add some pseudo code to my question...